# How can I create internal links with Sigil?

Tags: file-format, sigil, hyperlinking

I would like to add some internal links to an ebook I have—namely, adding links from the Table of Contents to the beginning of each chapters, and links at the end of each chapter to the TOC.

If I had an HTML file I would had had no problem: a bunch of anchors, and that would have been all. But starting with the epub, I am not sure which is the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it turned out that Insert->Link works even across files contained in the epub (and if it was really necessary I could use Insert->Anchor for inserting an anchor which I may use later). It is also possible to select some text, so that the link corresponds to the section selected.